# Notepad ++ Heredoc and Nowdoc PHP

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to fix the incorrect syntax highlighting in Notepad ++ for heredoc an nowdoc? It doesn't recognize the ending tag and makes the rest of the document highlighted as if it were in quotes.

Comment: Also, check the remainder of your code after your closing tag. For instance, a leftover double quote in your code misplaced can break the formatting.

Comment: This problem should hopefully be fixed soon. Here's the relevant issue on Github: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5264

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces and/or tabs.  The syntax highlighting for newdoc and heredoc in Notepad++ expects the closing tag to be at the far left.  Any indentation causes the syntax highlighting to break.

Answer (score 0):

Support for the flexible heredoc style was [added](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5264) in Notepad++ version 8.4.

You can fix this issue by downloading the latest version [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).